# Chrome Extension, Opening a "hidden" link

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome

Here's my pilot code:

```
function Addme(Test) {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.mysite.com/sendinfo?i="+test});
}
```

etc...

I'm putting together a website that will *grab an input* by the user and send it to the database via **url query**.

In the **example** code above, it will send the contents of the variable **test** into the database via query.

I know how to take care of the html part (user input, etc), what I don't know is how to do it without opening a new tab or anywhere at all for that matter. **The best thing would be to have it do it silently**, so it doesn't bother the user every time they want to register something.

Anyone know a way out of this?

Comment: Maybe you can use AJAX ([XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/))?

Comment: Maybe, care to give me an example? Edit: investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost/test/index.php?sql='+Value, false);
request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a database with a `REST` API, you can use an `XMLHttpRequest()` to send a URL query without disturbing/alerting the user.